# GROUP_CONCAT can't order by

Tags: mysql

I can't make GROUP_CONCAT make ORDER BY.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`cdlAmountA`+`cdlAmountB`+`cdlAmountC` SEPARATOR "|")
     FROM `creditlogs`
     WHERE `cdlDate` = "2016-04-07"
          AND compID = "AIR"
     ORDER BY `creditID`
```

This is out put.

```
96276.9|7960.2|0|0
```

But it's not right, The right answer is.

```
0|96276.9|7960.2|0
```

How can i make it right. And this is database.

```
creditID | cdlAmountA | cdlAmountB | cdlAmountC
-----------------------------------------------
1        | 0          | 0          | 0
2        | 34948.7    | 61328.2    | 0
3        | 4510.2     | 3450       | 0  
4        | 0          | 0          | 0
```

Comment: If you creditID is incremental in nature, you can remove OrderBY from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause has to be used *inside* [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`cdlAmountA`+`cdlAmountB`+`cdlAmountC` 
                    ORDER BY `creditID` SEPARATOR "|" )
FROM `creditlogs`
WHERE `cdlDate` = "2016-04-07" AND compID = "AIR"
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aafbe/3)

Comment: Thank you so much.